# AngularJS Controller gets destroyed if the DOM element gets "removed"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, dom

I have a directive that is attached to a angularjs controller, something like

```
<my-directive id="my-unique-directive" ng-controller="MyController"></my-directive>
```

inside my controller, on some point I need this directive to be gone. Then I mixed some jQuery into it so I can `$('#my-unique-directive').remove();`

It works fine, but am I doing that correctly? I know you're not supposed to access the DOM element inside the controller, but how else would I achieve this result?

To test if my Controller got destroyed I set up a function that will `console.log('I'm still here');` every one second, and this function is called right after I remove the DOM element. (Also, the function is attached to the controller itself, not the $scope)

That confirmed my worries: The Controller is not being destroyed, the log keeps showing even after the directive is removed.

How do I destroy the controller after destroying the DOM element?

Comment: Not sure what you've got against this controller? Does it really need to be destroyed? For a start don't use jQuery and maybe use an ng-if="dontShowMe"

Comment: Yep, ng-if will do this job for you http://plnkr.co/edit/t0MZrSmeAD0BQVKW9RVw?p=preview

Comment: I thought I needed to destroy the stance I created if I'm gonna reuse it on another place

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ng-if` will do this job for you:

```
<my-directive id="my-unique-directive" ng-controller="MyController" ng-if="!isDeleted"></my-directive>
```

Just setting `isDeleted` to true will remove element and related scope.

Notice:
If you store your controller to some variable it wont be destroyed. (Since garbage collector will not be able to collect it)
If you use $timeout(console.log('I am here'), 1000) - it still will be executed.
But this does not mean that controller exist.

Comment: I'm accustomed to destroy every single instance of every object I create because of Java, Pascal, etc. I thought the same rule would apply here... After I "ng-if" this directive, I will create the same thing on another place, that still is no problem right?